# Separating a List into Columns

Tags: r

I have this list in R:

```
my_list = list("word",c("word", "word"), "word", c("word", "word","word"), "word")

[[1]]
[1] "word"

[[2]]
[1] "word" "word"

[[3]]
[1] "word"

[[4]]
[1] "word" "word" "word"

[[5]]
[1] "word"
```

I would like to convert this list into a data frame that looks something like this:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1 word          
2 word word     
3 word          
4 word word word
5 word   

# source code of the desired output

structure(list(col1 = c("word", "word", "word", "word", "word"
), col2 = c("", "word", "", "word", ""), col3 = c("", "", "", 
"word", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I tried to use the answer provided here ([How to split a column of list into several columns using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014886/how-to-split-a-column-of-list-into-several-columns-using-r)) for my question:

```
z = my_list
x <- do.call(rbind, z)
colnames(x) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(x)]
h = data.frame(cbind(z[c("sg", "time")], x))
```

But this is not giving me the desired output.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lapply` to make the list element lengths the same, then `do.call` with `rbind` to create the desired output:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(my_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(my_list))))
```

Output

```
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
# [1,] "word" NA     NA    
# [2,] "word" "word" NA    
# [3,] "word" NA     NA    
# [4,] "word" "word" "word"
# [5,] "word" NA     NA
```

If you wanted there to be blanks as opposed to `NA` values:

```
new_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(my_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(my_list))))
new_df[is.na(new_df)] <- ""
```

Output:

```
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
# [1,] "word" ""     ""    
# [2,] "word" "word" ""    
# [3,] "word" ""     ""    
# [4,] "word" "word" "word"
# [5,] "word" ""     ""
```

Comment: @ jpsmith : thank you for your answer! I was about to make a quick modification to your answer with the following code:

Comment: p = data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(my_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(my_list)))))

Comment: p[is.na(p)] <- " "

Comment: Good answer, I'd put the `max` calculation outside the loop though.

Comment: # source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592706/replace-missing-values-na-with-blank-empty-string

Comment: But it looks like you have already added this! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

With `stringi::stri_list2matrix`:

```r
library(stringi)
data.frame(stri_list2matrix(my_list, byrow = TRUE))
#     X1   X2   X3
# 1 word <NA> <NA>
# 2 word word <NA>
# 3 word <NA> <NA>
# 4 word word word
# 5 word <NA> <NA>
```

Or with `sapply`:

```r
t(sapply(my_list, "length<-", max(lengths(my_list))))
```